# Why is this Hotspot JVM option not the default? -XX:+PrintConcurrentLocks

Tags: java, stack-dump

By default, with Hotspot, a CTRL-Break thread dump will not list what threads are holding `java.lang.concurrent` locks.  And I understand that with these locks, Hotspot cannot have information about at which stack frame a lock was acquired.  If you add the JVM option `-XX:+PrintConcurrentLocks`, then a CTRL-Break stack dump will list (after a thread's stack trace) any concurrent locks held by that frame.  For example:

```
"D-Java-5-Lock" prio=6 tid=0x00000000069a1800 nid=0x196c runnable [0x000000000770f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at com.Tester.longDelay(Tester.java:41)
      at com.Tester$D.run(Tester.java:88)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
      - <0x00000007d6030898> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

Without this option, it isn't possible to figure out what thread is holding this lock in a post-mortem.  Why is this option not the default?  Is there some non-obvious performance or stability penalty?  When I search to find discussion of this, nothing comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked Oracle (my employer has a support contact) and the answer is basically that the option is safe to use and that many purely-diagnostic features are disabled by default and this is one of those options.  IMO, if a diagnostic feature is safe and stable and doesn't introduce a performance penalty, then it should be on by default.  It appears that this is not the view at (then) Sun and (now) Oracle.

Comment: add explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, my guess is that it is unstable, or the JVM maintainers (Sun-now-Oracle) simply don't want to maintain it as a supported feature.  You can tell this simply by the `-XX:` prefix:

> Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are not recommended for casual use. These options are subject to change without notice.

*- from [Java HotSpot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)*

Also from that page, that option can be dynamically enabled or disabled via the JDK management interface, so you can enable it via an MXBean if you need.

> Flags marked as manageable are dynamically writeable through the JDK management interface (com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean API) and also through JConsole. In Monitoring and Managing Java SE 6 Platform Applications, Figure 3 shows an example. The manageable flags can also be set through jinfo -flag.

Finally, the [jstack](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) Stack Trace tool can perform the same functionality at any time without requiring it enabled all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Because only ReentrantLocks know which threads they are related to. To get this information on Runtime a realization of this method should go over the heap to find all locks and their threads.